# Android HttpHelper

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I want a helper class for http connection. I am able to write simple code to connect using HttpUrlConnection and Async task and it works well.

But I am confused how can I write a more generic reusable class HttpHelper.

I got this [HttpHelper](https://gist.github.com/9173052) class from internet (It just does a simple get call, I will later extend it to deal with post calls with query parameters), but I am not able to figure out how to call/use this as is. I am confused with the callbacks and the generics.

If I want to make a http request using this call and expect String result, this is what I attempted and it is all with syntax errors.

```
    HttpHelper<String> api = new HttpHelper<>();
    api.get("www.google.com", new HttpHelper.Callback<String>{
        @Override
        String execute(String html){
        }
        @Override
        void finish(String result){
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help

K

Answer (score 1):

you have to call your method like this:

```
     HttpHelper<String> api = new HttpHelper<String>(); 
     api.get("www.google.com", new HttpHelper.Callback<String>{ 
        @Override 
        String execute(String html){

         return html; // This line is very very important.
        } 
        @Override 
        void finish(String result){

        //  Do whatever you wan to do with your server response.
        } 
    });
```

And do check your imports which HttpHelper class your are importing.

This works for me . Happy Coding !!!

Comment: You are missing () it should be `new HttpHelper.Callback<String>(){...}`
But you answer works!